# Analytical solution for a linear matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve analytically the following system?
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 - x_2 &= 1\\
-1/2x_1 + x_2 -1/2x_3 &= 1\\
-1/2x_1 + x_3 -1/2x_4 &= 1\\
\vdots\\
-1/2x_1 + x_i -1/2x_{i+1} &= 1\\
\vdots\\
-1/2x_1 + x_{n-1} &= 1\\
x_n &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Is there a strategy for solving system with recursive nature like the one above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a general strategy for such systems, but for your case I would do the following. Adding the first two equations gives $1/2x_1 - 1/2x_3 = 2$, so that $x_1 - x_3 = 4$. Adding that to the third eq. and multiplying by two gives: $x_1 - x_4 = 10$. And you can keep on doing the same, giving $x_1 - x_i = 3*2^{i-2}-2$, until you reach: $x_1 - x_{n-1} = 3*2^{n-3}-2$, (for $n>3$). Then, you can solve the system:\begin{align}
x_1 - x_{n-1} &= 3*2^{n-3}-2\\
-1/2x_1 + x_{n-1} &= 1\\
\end{align}
which gives $x_1 = 3*2^{n-2}-2$ and $x_i = 3*(2^{n-2}-2^{i-2})$ (for all $i \le n$)